# Using AngularJS ui router breaks behaviour of custom bootstrap theme

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using **AngularJS UI router** in an HTML5 application with a custom Bootstrap theme bought from [Themeforest](http://themeforest.net/item/material-admin-bootstrap-admin-html5-app/10646222?s_phrase=crm&s_rank=4). The issue is that this theme has some components that rely on both the *href*, *data-toggle* and *data-dismissal* attributes and UI Router breaks them. For example:

```
<a href="#offcanvas-map-tools" class="link" data-toggle="offcanvas">Show</a>
```

Would show an off-canvas component when being cliked.

How can i configure AngularJS UI router as to avoid breaking the behaviour of this theme's Components?

Comment: I fail to see how a router has anything to do with HTML and CSS markup. All the router does is changing the template/controller based on the URL.

Comment: It does since by default **angular ui router** interprets all _href_ attributes with '#' in them as routes for its navigation configutation. This overrides the default behaviour that the theme component uses, since this same behaviour is on Bootstrap.

Comment: Ah, so it's not really the theme, but the JavaScript code that comes with it. And it's not really the router, but the standard location service. Try using the html5 mode. Or use a programmatic approach rather than an approach relying on data attributes and element IDs. This doesn't fit well with angular.

Comment: Yes exactly, the theme works but the javascript behaviour of its components get messed up. I'll try to see if a programmatic approach is possible. Exactly, what do you mean by using the html5 mode?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes

Comment: $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing this custom directive to handle the theme's javascript behaviour using the theme's Javascript API:

```
app.directive('offcanvasToggler', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope : {
            target: '@',
            backdrop : '=useBackdrop'
        },
        templateUrl : 'directives/toggle-offcanvas.html',
        link: function($scope, $element){
            var anchor = $element.find('a');
            anchor.on('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                materialadmin.AppOffcanvas._handleOffcanvasOpen(anchor);
            });
        }
    };
});
```